# How to set up custom Emmett snippets in VS Code installed on Linux Mint?

Tags: visual-studio-code, linux-mint

How do I set up the following Emmet custom snippets in VS Code installed on Linux Mint?.

The windows example is below, BUT I am on Linux Mint and I don't know how to add the path needed and replace it with my Linux path.

> {
> ...
> "emmet.extensionsPath": "C:\Users\jonah\emmet",
> }

> /home/will/Documents/code/snippets/custom-snippets.json

As I would like to use this to add custom code snippets to speed up my coding projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting should just be:

`{ ... "emmet.extensionsPath": "/home/will/Documents/code/snippets" ...}`